# Bindable EventHandler in Xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms

I made a custom entry in xamarin and added some bindable property in it. now i need to add Textchanged and other event handler property in it but i'm onto how to add them. 
please help.

Comment: Can you please share us some relevant code about your custom entry? And what you exactly want because I think Dima Kravchyk's answer answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you inherit your custom entry from basic entry, then you will already have TextChanged event.
For additional event you need add event in custom control

```
public class CustomEntry : Entry
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public CustomEntry() { }
}
```

And them using it in xaml

```
<controls:CustomEntry MyEvent="CustomEntry_MyEvent" />
```

For invoke this event in renderer you need create method in custom control and invoke event in this method.

Comment: maybe you need something like MyEvent={Binding Something} ?